# Could not execute method for android:onClick ERROR

Tags: java, android, onclick

I want to display a number text that increases if the statement is true and to show the number in a text view, the error comes when I change the text view text when the number is increased.

```java
 int stars = 0; //Global variable

//onClick{...}

public void changeTextViewToStarsNumber(){
  if(editText.getText().equals("153"){
     stars = stars + 10;
     textView.setText(stars); //The error line
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Consider posting your error message.

Comment: I don't understand your question properly. But it seems you are passing `int` into `setText `method. Try to change it `textView.setText(stars.toString())`

Comment: Probably won't work with `stars.toString()`, use `String.valueof(stars)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the error line to `textView.setText(String.valueOf(stars));`

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer. even if your answer is correct and accepted, try to explain your answer to teach someone something :) friendly tip

Answer (score 1):

Is your error at compilation? If so, then I am guessing you need to parse your `stars` into a String.

```java
textView.setText(String.valueOf(stars)); //The error line
```

Answer (score 0):

.setText() needs a String value
You need to convert your starts to a String type, by using valueOf() function.